# Replace author-year citation with superscript numbers and move the citation itself to the margin of the frame (beamer)

Tags: beamer, margins, natbib

I would like to use author-year citation but its length can be distracting for the reader. I still want to mention author names and dates explicitly because this shows the chronological progress of the literature. Thus, I would like to place the author-year citation to the left with (say) 2mm margin where each reference being numbered on its own line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}

\newlength{\widthTextMarginLeft}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginLeft}{1.5mm}
\newlength{\widthTextMarginRight}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginRight}{2mm}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=\widthTextMarginLeft, text margin right=\widthTextMarginRight}
\newlength{\widthSideBar}
\setlength{\widthSideBar}{0.3\paperwidth}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\widthSideBar, sidebar width right=0cm}

        % ===== Custom margin codes for pagewide frames =====
% BEGIN_FOLD

            % Set margins
            \newlength{\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide}
            \setlength{\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide}{5mm}
            \newlength{\widthTextMarginRightPageWide}
            \setlength{\widthTextMarginRightPageWide}{5mm}

            % Command to change margins for a page wide
            \makeatletter
            \newcommand{\framePageWide}{
                    \def\Gm@lmargin{\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide}%
                    \def\Gm@rmargin{\widthTextMarginRightPageWide}%
                    \textwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth-\Gm@lmargin-\Gm@rmargin\relax
                    \hsize\textwidth
                    \columnwidth\textwidth
                    \setlength{\linewidth}{\textwidth}
                    \hoffset=\dimexpr-\beamer@leftsidebar+\Gm@lmargin-\widthTextMarginLeft\relax % IMPORTANT: \widthTextMarginLeft is not to be changed to \widthTextMarginLeftPageWide
                                        }
            \makeatother

% END_FOLD

\usepackage{natbib}

\hypersetup{citecolor=SlateBlue2, citebordercolor=SlateBlue2, 
    linkcolor=DodgerBlue3, linkbordercolor=DodgerBlue3, urlcolor=Blue1, colorlinks=true}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}

    Cite \cite{wu2017,MRITS-Grant2014,earnest2015}

    Cite \textsuperscript{\color{SlateBlue2} 1,} \textsuperscript{\color{SlateBlue2} 2,} \textsuperscript{\color{SlateBlue2} 3}

\end{frame}


{\framePageWide

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.9]{Referencing}



\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}

\bibliography{sample_margin}

\end{frame}

}



\end{document}
```

Contents of the `.bib` file

```
@book{earnest2015,
  title={Wind Power Technology},
  author={Joshua Earnest},
  year={2015},
  publisher={PHI Learning}
}

@techreport{MRITS-Grant2014,
     title = {{Report in the Matter of Integration and Transmission Study for the Future Renewable Energy Standard}},
     author = {Grant},
     group = {Minnesota Department of Commerce},
     year = {2014},
     institution = {Minnesota Department of Commerce},
     month = {Nov},
     Date-Added = {2014},
     Date-Modified = {2014}
}

@ARTICLE{wu2017,
  title={{Assessing Impact of Renewable Energy Integration on System Strength Using Site-Dependent Short Circuit Ratio}},
  author={Wu, Di and Li, Gangan and Javadi, Milad and Malyscheff, Alexander M and Hong, Mingguo and Jiang, John Ning},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on Sustainable Energy},
  year={2017},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some starting point, but you'll have to make sure yourself, that you only use one `\inmargin` command per line.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{crane}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}

\newlength{\widthSideBar}
\setlength{\widthSideBar}{0.3\paperwidth}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\widthSideBar, sidebar width right=0cm}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{earnest2015,
  title={Wind Power Technology},
  author={Joshua Earnest},
  year={2015},
  publisher={PHI Learning}
}

@techreport{MRITS-Grant2014,
     title = {{Report in the Matter of Integration and Transmission Study for the Future Renewable Energy Standard}},
     author = {Grant},
     group = {Minnesota Department of Commerce},
     year = {2014},
     institution = {Minnesota Department of Commerce},
     month = {Nov},
     Date-Added = {2014},
     Date-Modified = {2014}
}

@ARTICLE{wu2017,
  title={{Assessing Impact of Renewable Energy Integration on System Strength Using Site-Dependent Short Circuit Ratio}},
  author={Wu, Di and Li, Gangan and Javadi, Milad and Malyscheff, Alexander M and Hong, Mingguo and Jiang, John Ning},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on Sustainable Energy},
  year={2017},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\inmargin}[1]{\beamer@putleft{\cite{#1}}{2.5ex}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}

    \inmargin{MRITS-Grant2014}Cite \textsuperscript{\color{SlateBlue2} 1,}\linebreak\inmargin{wu2017}Cite \textsuperscript{\color{SlateBlue2} 2,}


\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.9]{Referencing}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```